# How to run Scenario Outline in PyCharm 4 with Lettuce runner

Tags: python-2.7, bdd, pycharm, lettuce

I have simple feature:

```
Feature: Lol and other words

Scenario: Lol printing
  Given I like print "lol"

Scenario Outline: Words printing
  Given I like print "<word>"
Examples:
| word |
| lol  |
| ala  |
```

And implementation:

```
from lettuce import step

@step('I like print "([^"]+)"')
def step_impl(step, word):
    print word
```

When PyCharm lettuce test runner execute feature its run first scenario without problems but second is never executed (however it knows that there is other scenario) - so it looks like:
[image]
How to run `Scenario Outline` with this runner?
System:
Windows 8.1, PyCharm 4.0.1 139.556 EAP Professional, lettuce 0.2.20, Python27

Answer (score 1):

This is bug and it is reported to JetBrains team:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14572#tab=Comments